# Concatenated where conditional in SAS

Tags: sas, concatenation, where-clause

I am trying to write a macro to perform a proc summary operation on a dataset.

This macro takes in a few variables:

- lower bound date (start = `'01Jan2013'd`)
- upper bound date (end = `'01Jan2016'd`)
- an additional 'and' condition (sometimes `''`, sometimes `'and state = XXX'`)

These variables are fed into the where statement in the macro below. Note that there will sometimes be an 'and' condition, and sometimes not at all.

```
%macro program1(start,end,cond); %macro _(); %mend _;
    proc summary data = data1 nway missing;
        where &start. < month < &end. || &cond.;
        class month_inc;
        var var1 var2;
        output out =summ_data1 sum=;
    run;
%mend;
```

I am having trouble getting the macro variables to work correctly in the where statement. The `||` doesn't work.

I tried to use CATX like so:

```
where catx(' ',&start. le month_inc le &end.,&cond.);
```

And that works to an extent. The `&start.` and `&end.` variables resolves as numerical values instead of the SAS dates, thus not summarizing my results correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you literally pass in the keyword AND as part of the value of the parameter COND (`cond=and state='XXX'`) then just remove the concatenation operator from your WHERE statement.

```
where (&start<month<&end) &cond ;
```

Otherwise use macro logic to conditionally generate the part that references the optional COND value.

I like to use the `WHERE ALSO` (also known as `where and`) statement to augment existing `WHERE` statements.

```
%macro program1(start,end,cond); 
  proc summary data = data1 nway missing;
    where &start. < month < &end. ;
%if %length(&cond) %then %do;
    where also &cond.;
%end;
    class month_inc;
    var var1 var2;
    output out =summ_data1 sum=;
  run;
%mend;
```

So then your example call could look like this:

```
%program1(start = '01Jan2013'd
         ,end = '01Jan2016'd
         ,cond = state = 'XXX')
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, your syntax works but the dates are not working correctly. 

I'm still getting data rows with date ranges prior to 2013

Comment: For that type of issue you need to provide some example data to explain your issue. Input data and expected results.